# puppet on debian

Tags: debian, puppet

I run debian 9, and have installed packages `puppet` and `puppet-master`; they are listed as version `4.8.2`. In the learning material I have found so far, I come across commands `puppetd` and `puppetca` - which I don't have. A search with `apt-file` only finds some bash-completion files that refer to these commands. Are things simply called something else in debian?

Comment: I do not know the exact answer, but please note that Debian 9 contains Puppet4. But Debian 10 contains Puppet5 (and Debian 10 is the current stable Debian release) . Puppet's own current release is already Puppet6. Puppet major releases are know for their rather big changes (sadly, if you ask me).

Comment: It sounds like the documentation you are reading is not correct.  CA operations are normally handled by the command `puppet ca` and the server Daemon is started with `puppet master`.  Also as HKoof mentioned if you are just starting out i would strongly urge you to start with buster